# How does terminal (bash) know what exception was raised

Tags: c++, bash, exception

Consider the following code:

```cpp
int main() {
  auto f = 0;
  auto g = 1 / f;
}
```

Running this does the following:

```sh
]$ g++ main.cpp                                   
]$ ./a.out                                        
Floating point exception (core dumped)
]$ echo $?                                        
136
```

Now, I know that an FPE was raised with value 8.

```
]$ man 7 signal
...
    SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
...
```

I am curious how bash knows what exception was thrown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an exception that was thrown. The process was terminated by a signal.

A parent process receives notification when it's child process terminates; and the reason for the termination gets returned from the `wait()` system call (which the parent process uses for that purpose). This includes the signal number, if the child process was terminated by a signal.

You will find more information from the

```
$ man 2 wait
```

manual page:

```
   WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)
          returns true if the child process was terminated by a signal.

   WTERMSIG(wstatus)
          returns the number of the signal that caused the  child  process
          to terminate.  This macro should be employed only if WIFSIGNALED
          returned true.
```

Comment: I.e. it's entirely separate from C++ exceptions and unrelated to try/catch/throw and such. This particular signal just happens to have "Exception" in the name.